# ulimit: Unknown option “-r”

Tags: realtime, ulimit

I'm trying to get JACK running in RT mode and I need to determine whether I'm allowed the necessary real time priority. Around the internet I found that `ulimit -r` or more genreally `ulimit -a` can tell me exactly that but today, on Ubuntu Gnome 16.10, `ulimit` has no `-r` option. What is the alternative?

Comment: Please paste the terminal output, including the line where you enter `ulimit -r` into your question, select it, and press the `{}` button.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex It's what's in the question title - ``ulimit: Unknown option "-r"`` (and other informative stuff like which option prints help).

Comment: That doesn't happen on 16.10 here. I need to see what you typed and what was output. Please copy and paste the entire input and output.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I'm so sorry, I'm an idiot. I'm using fish shell by default. In bash, it works, of course. I'll probably delete the question.

Comment: It might be better to answer your question below. That way, if others get that error message, it'll show up here and in Google.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Yeah, you're probably right. That was the other option I was considering.

Answer (score 3):

The problem turned out to be the fact that I was using fish shell. The `ulimit` command there is obviously a different thing that the one in bash. In bash, it works as expected.